# Unit Testing an Android application in Bamboo, Hudson, or any CI servers

Tags: android, continuous-integration

it seems that running an Android Test requires that a device or emulator is present. even this article: http://code.google.com/p/the-missing-android-xml-junit-test-runner/ requires it.

does anyone able to setup Android Tests in a CI server? kindly enlighten me on how to do the setup.

thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately I have not finished this task yet. But think I'm close to it.
We use Jenkins as an integration server.

Android emulator has a nice option

```
-no-window
```

I managed to run emulator with this option on our Ubuntu server without any X-server.

So I'm going to implement the following steps:

1. Create a dedicated AVD for running tests (not sure about their count, but we start with one AVD and one Android project and one job :) )
2. The first build step will be to run an emulator with -no-window
3. The second step - install application packages using adb. Here is one pretty feature of adb install command: it will finish after installation is completed only. So we don't worry about long emulator startup.
4. And the last step - run tests using

   adb shell am instrument

There is also a task of gathering JUnit reports. I have not touched it yet... But I'm sure it's possible :)

Comment: Regarding JUnit reports, take a look at https://github.com/jsankey/android-junit-report

Answer (score 4):

You might want to take a look at this Jenkins plugin:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Android+Emulator+Plugin

We've been using it with reasonable success.

Comment: thanks for that info. is there an equivalent Bamboo plugin? we're currently using Bamboo.

Comment: Really nice plugin. It resolves the problem of running different emulators simultaneously.

Comment: @firnnauriel I wrote this Jenkins plugin, but I haven't heard of equivalents for other CI systems. Just one more reason to use Jenkins! ;)